# Convert PHP Script (type, length, trim) to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

What would be the equivalent of this PHP script in Javascript?  All it does is check sString to see if it is all digits and equal to 5 in length.  If true it trims the leading zeros.  I don't have a choice to keep it all server side with PHP because of the varying places the searches (sString) are coming in from (websites, apps, etc that all use a central search engine).  In other words, the reason I need it in multiple languages is because the actual string (search query) is being sent to a 3rd party, un-editable, search engine and it's being sent from multiple platforms.

```
if (ctype_digit($sString) == true) {
    if (strlen($sString) == 5){
       $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: alert($sString[4] && +$sString); converts a 5digit string to a number or false. feel free to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if a string is all digits (and length of 5):

```
/^\d{5}$/.test("00123")
```

Trim all the starting zeroes:

```
"00123".replace(/^0*/, "")
```

Bringing it all together:

```
var str = "00123";

if (/^\d{5}$/.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(/^0*/, "");
}

// str is now "123"
```

Read more about the power of regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/^\d{5}$/.test(str)) {
   str = parseInt(str); // use parseFloat if needed 
}
```